# Android Change Button text randomly

Tags: android, button

How to change button text every 5 secs ? i,e  First the text will be "hello" and after 5 secs it should be "Hi" and then "hello" and then "hi" and so on until I click that button.

Comment: use java.util.TimerTask , start timer on resume and stop it on button click

Comment: @sabersafavi how to change text  i,e toggling of text . I have two words "hello " and "hi" which should change one after another. In run method() i can change once and i am unable to change to different text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Alternate can be using the `ViewFlipper`. I think it will be more easier if you want to show few number of views.

Here is an example -

```
<ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Hi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        /> <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        /> <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="How are you"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        />
    </ViewFlipper>
```

and the Java Code is -

```
ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
        viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
        viewFlipper.startFlipping();
```